# How can you prove that: A-(A∩B)=A-B ?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, formal-proofs

I know this might be stupid for most of the people here. I am starting with set theory and I cannot prove this:A-(A∩B)=A-B

I start by assuming: 1) x∈A & ¬ (x∈A & x∈B)

```
     Therefore I understand I can infer: 

             2) x∈A                  from 1
             3) ¬ (x∈A & x∈B)        from 1
             4) ¬x∈A & ¬x∈A          from 3
             5) ¬x∈A                 from 4
             6) ⊥                    from 2 and 5
```

I do not know how to turn around this contradiction. At an intuitively level it is very clear to me, but I am not able to formalize it.

Comment: Step 4) is wrong: see De Morgan's laws.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
x \in A - (A\cap B) 
&\iff x \in A \; \wedge \; x \notin A\cap B \\
&\iff x \in A \; \wedge \; (x\notin A \: \vee \: x \notin B) \\
&\iff x \in A \; \wedge \; x \notin B \\
&\iff x \in A -B.
\end{align*}

Comment: It may be better for the asker if you show the steps $ x \in A \wedge (x \notin A \vee x \notin B) \iff (x \in A \wedge x \notin A) \, \vee\, (x \in A \, \wedge \, x \notin B) \iff x \in A \, \wedge x \notin B $, where it's clear you use distributive and $\bot$-neutrality

Comment: Isn't $x \in A \; \wedge \; x \notin A\cap B \\$ a contraction? If $x \in X$ then it must be that $x \in A\cap B \\$? May be a stupid question, but I'm trying to understand set theory.

Comment: @pafnuti If $A \subset B$ then it would be a contradiction (not really, since the proposition would yield the empty set). Otherwise not, take for instance $A =[0,2]$ and $B = [1,3]$.

Comment: Yes of course, silly of me.

Answer (score 1):

You'd do this by set inclusion.
If we can show that $A - (A \cap B) \subset A-B$, and that $A-B \subset A - (A \cap B)$, we'd conclude equality.

So let $x \in A-B$. Then $x \in A, x \notin B$, so $x \notin A \cap B$, and so $x \in A - (A \cap B)$.

If $x \in A - (A \cap B)$, $x\in A$ but not in $ A \cap B$. If $x \in B$ we'd have a contradiction. That finishes the proof.